# Eclipse says package declaration does not match expected package ""

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am using Maven to build my project. When I view it in Eclipse, it complains that

> package declaration does not match expected package ""

Maven is able to successfully build the project though.

[image: Eclipse Project View]

Comment: If you are using maven, I suggest using 'mvn eclipse:eclipse' and then import it as a regular java project (Import existing).

Comment: The folder `WebContent` does not look like a usual Maven WAR project.

Comment: @rethab: It really worked for me , thanks so much.Idk , why others down voting here.

Comment: @Chetan I edited my Answer to include a little bit more background (see below).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eclipse needs to recognize a certain folder as a 'Source Folder' in order to correctly interpret the contents as Java source files.

Typically, if you create a Java project, Eclipse creates one folder called 'src' and marks it as 'Source Folder'. If you are dealing with a default Maven project setup, however, Eclipse will not automagically recognize 'src/main/java' as a source folder (unless you are using a plugin of course).

If you are not sure whether Eclipse sees your folder as a 'Source Folder' or just a regular folder, take look at the icons (note the small package symbol on the lower left corner):

[image]

Since you are, as you stated, working with Maven, you should either use a Maven plugin for Eclipse or have Maven generate the required meta-files for Eclipse. This can be done with the command (generates .classpath and .project files):

> mvn eclipse:eclipse

People who are not using Maven, but face this issue, can right-click on their source folder and mark it as source folder with 'Build Path -> Use as source folder'.

Comment: using mvn eclipse:eclipse produces the issue the user was getting even if using the maven plugin

Comment: What you have to do is replace "<classpathentry kind="src" path="." including="**/*.java"/>" with "<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>"

Comment: @user18896654353 In my case the path was already "src/main/java" but this was wrong.  It needed to be "src/test/java".  The change does not take effect until you close the project and re-open it.  Just doing a Project > Clean... is not sufficient.  For those who don't already know,  this is inside Eclipse's .classpath file (no extension).

Comment: @rethab I'm getting this error message when I create a new project and then create a file (with a package declaration) in the src directory. Any ideas as to why?